# Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "request body stream exhausted"

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am getting the NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "request body stream exhausted"

NSLocalizedDescription=request body stream exhausted, NSUnderlyingError=0x2088c080 "request body stream exhausted"}

This error is generated when uploading multiple big size images
I am using AFNetworking and tried to search for a fix online, but didn't succeed

```
NSDictionary *clientUniqueId = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSLocalizedString(uniqueDrId, nil) forKey:@"clientUniqueId"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                 path:pendingUpload.urlPath
                                                           parameters:clientUniqueId
                                            constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                {
                                    [formData appendPartWithFormData:[pendingUpload dataRecordData] name:@"dr"];
                                    NSArray *attachments = pendingUpload.attachments;
                                    if (attachments != nil) {
                                        for (Attachment *attachment in attachments) {


                                            [formData appendPartWithFileData:attachment.data
                                                                        name:attachment.key
                                                                    fileName:attachment.filename
                                                                    mimeType:attachment.contentType];


                                        }
                                    }

                                }];
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem. I am also having same problem. Please help me.

Comment: it was a server config issue in my case

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [AFNetworking FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ):

> **Why are some upload requests failing with the error "request body stream exhausted"? What does that mean, and how do I fix this?**
>
> When uploading over a 3G or EDGE connection, requests may fail with "request body stream exhausted". Using `-throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:delay:` your multipart form construction block, you can set a maximum packet size and delay according to the recommended values (`kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedPacketSize` and `kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedDelay`). This lowers the risk of the input stream exceeding its allocated bandwidth. Unfortunately, as of iOS 6, there is no definite way to distinguish between a 3G, EDGE, or LTE connection. As such, it is not recommended that you throttle bandwidth based solely on network reachability. Instead, you should consider checking for the "request body stream exhausted" in a failure block, and then retrying the request with throttled bandwidth.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing this issue also and didn't have any luck with the `throttleBandwithWithPacketSize` method. I believe in my case it was an authentication challenge issue.

What I finally did was switch to the URLSession connection method in AFNetworking 2.0 and that seemed to solve it for me. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
    NSString *uploadAttachmentURL = @"https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=screenshot.jpeg";

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    _afHTTPSessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    // hack to allow 'text/plain' content-type to work
    NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:_AFOpManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
    [contentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
    _afHTTPSessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes;

    [_afHTTPSessionManager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"[USERNAME]" password:@"[PASSWORD]"];



    [_afHTTPSessionManager POST:uploadAttachmentURL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"screenshot" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        DDLogError(@"screenshot operation success!  %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        DDLogError(@"Operation Error: %@", error);
    }];
```